# Do the NA releases of Radiant Historia, Kingdom Hearts 358/2 and The World Ends With You have dual audio (japanese)?

Tags: kingdom-hearts, the-world-ends-with-you, radiant-historia

Can the NA releases of the following nintendo DS games be played with Japanese audio but english subtitles from in game settings?

- Radiant Historia
- Kingdom Hearts 358/2
- The World Ends With You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those games can be played with japanese audio in their english releases:

- Radiant Historia has no voice acting so that wouldn't be an option.
- Both Kingdom Hearts Days and The World Ends With You offer no such option.